# How to encrypt string in Java and decrypt in Python?

Tags: java, python, encryption, aes

I have encrypted a string in Java using AES, and decrypt in Python. But, after decrypting in Python there are random chars here, not the expected output.

```
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import android.util.Base64;

public class AESCrypt{

public static final byte[] encBytes(byte[] srcBytes, byte[] key,
        byte[] newIv) throws Exception {
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
    IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(newIv);
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, iv);
    byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(srcBytes);
    return encrypted;
}

public static final String encText(String sSrc)
        throws Exception {
    byte[] key = 
    {'a','r','e','y','o','u','o','k','a','r','e','y','o','u','o','k'};
    byte[] ivk = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
    byte[] srcBytes = sSrc.getBytes("utf-8");
    byte[] encrypted = encBytes(srcBytes, key, ivk);
    return Base64.encodeToString(encrypted,Base64.DEFAULT);
}

}
```

and python code is :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from Crypto.Cipher import AES
import base64

key = 'areyouokareyouok'
iv = '0000000000000000'

BS = 16
pad = lambda s: s + (BS - len(s) % BS) * chr(BS - len(s) % BS) 
unpad = lambda s : s[0:-ord(s[-1])]

def decrypt_aes(cryptedStr):
    generator = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
    cryptedStr = base64.b64decode(cryptedStr)
    recovery = generator.decrypt(cryptedStr)
    return unpad(recovery)

sourceStr = 'Dur/0RHadPwToNWczq8xk3mBdjybyw/yaMgas1F+WLg='

print decrypt_aes(sourceStr)
```

I can not understand why? Padding?

Comment: In Java, your IV is `0x00` repeated 16 times.  In Python, your IV is `0x30` repeated 16 times.  These aren't the same, obviously.

Comment: Hi Luke：Great thanks!

Comment: You're welcome.  Might also be wise to not do the padding yourself manually.

Answer (score 0):

I am using `Python >= 3.5`. Your java encrypted data can be decrypted using `pycryptodome` in the following way:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import base64
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Util.Padding import unpad

key = 'areyouokareyouok'
_iv = "\x00"*AES.block_size # creates a 16 byte zero initialized string

def decrypt_aes(cryptedStr):
    generator = AES.new(key.encode(), AES.MODE_CBC, _iv.encode())
    cryptedStr_bytes = base64.b64decode(cryptedStr)
    recovery = generator.decrypt(cryptedStr_bytes)
    return unpad(recovery, AES.block_size)

sourceStr = 'Dur/0RHadPwToNWczq8xk3mBdjybyw/yaMgas1F+WLg='

print(f"Output - {decrypt_aes(sourceStr)}") 
#Output - b'$PQWP6,014541.20,00000008*11\r\n'
```

I have knowingly not decoded the final decrypted bytes to string to display there was one carriage return and one newline character at the end of the original string.